# Adding the sum of cells from multiple tabs that may be a number O

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am compiling a workbook with multiple tabs.  I need the figure out how each location did, however, some were closed for some monthly reports, therefore in the cell, I put "closed".  If the location was opened, there would be a number in the cell with the total sales.  It is a workbook with over 5 years of monthly volumes so a formula is a must! Each month is a tab.  I can't seem to find a simple formula to add the totals and not give me a #VALUE message because the formula was not able to pick up on the text in some cells.

Thank you!

Comment: Could you please share us with a simple sample? Besides, you can show us what's the "text" in some cells.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading you correctly, a simplified example would be the following

Sheets 1, 2 & 3 have values in cell A1, these values are respectively

1, Closed, 2

As Sheet2!A1 is a text value, some formulas will present #VALUE!

for example the following will error
=SUM(Sheet1!A1+Sheet2!A1+Sheet3!A1)

To correct this try
=SUM(Sheet1:Sheet3!A1)

Or replace the + with comma's as this seems to work too

=SUM(Sheet1!A1,Sheet2!A1,Sheet3!A1)